# using multiple find_in_set in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

im using the following query for a find_in_set multiple condition query.. any idea what's the issue with this and how can i improve it?

```sql
SELECT `profile`.*,`extend`.* ,`online`.`hash` AS `online` FROM `skadate_profile` AS `profile`
 LEFT JOIN `skadate_profile_extended` AS `extend` USING( `profile_id` ) LEFT JOIN `skadate_profile_online` AS `online` USING( `profile_id` ) 
WHERE `profile`.`profile_id`!= 152 AND `profile`.`profile_id` NOT IN ( SELECT `blocked_id` FROM `skadate_profile_block_list` WHERE `profile_id` =152 )
 OR SELECT FIND_IN_SET('1','1') > 0 OR SELECT FIND_IN_SET('189','445') > 0
  OR SELECT FIND_IN_SET('2','2') > 0 OR SELECT FIND_IN_SET('9','1') > 0 AND 
 `profile`.`profile_id`!= 152 AND `profile`.`sex` != 2 LIMIT 0, 10
```

This is the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT FIND_IN_SET('1','1') > 0 OR SELECT FIND_IN_SET('189','445') > 0 OR SELECT' at line 1

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) what is the error message?

Comment: Hey thanks, below is the error, "  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT FIND_IN_SET('1','1') > 0 OR SELECT FIND_IN_SET('189','445') > 0 OR SELECT' at line 1"